# How to move element from its position to a center

Tags: html, jquery, css, animation

I have three elements and once I clicked one of it I want to move it to the center but from its position with a transition of, for example, 1 second. Also, I want to increase fade the text and show another text during the time when the box increases from 150px to 200px but for now I just don't know how to center it on a click. I did it but it goes from bottom right to the center but I want it to go from its position.

Also, I tried using $(this) to get certain div but it just didn't work

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.second').click(e => {
    $('.second').addClass('red')
  })
  
    
});
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  height: 90vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000;
}

.red {
  position: absolute;
top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  transition: 1s ease;
  color: red;
  @keyframes rise;

@keyframes rise {
 0% { width: 200px; height: 200px }
 100% { width: 150px; height: 150px }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main'>
  <div class="first block">Hello</div>
  <div class="second block">Hi</div>
  <div class="third block">hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because everything is transitioning,
the sequence of centering the div in your code is like this:
First, its position becomes absolute
then it goes to the bottom right direction because you have `top 50%; left 50%;`
then it comes back to the center because of `transform: translate( -50%, -50%)`
You can fix it to ways:

1. Change the centering method to margins

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.second').click(e => {
    $('.second').addClass('red')
  })
  
    
});
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  height: 90vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000;
}

.red {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  transition:  1s ease;
  color: red;
  @keyframes rise;

@keyframes rise {
 0% { width: 200px; height: 200px }
 100% { width: 150px; height: 150px }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main'>
  <div class="first block">Hello</div>
  <div class="second block">Hi</div>
  <div class="third block">hello</div>
</div>
```

In this way, the div goes nowhere, just to the center.

2. Second way is to not transition `position` and `transform`

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.second').click(e => {
    $('.second').addClass('red')
  })
  
    
});
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  height: 90vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000;
}

.red {
  position: absolute;
top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  transition: 1s ease;
  transition-property: width, height, color;
  color: red;
  @keyframes rise;

@keyframes rise {
 0% { width: 200px; height: 200px }
 100% { width: 150px; height: 150px }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main'>
  <div class="first block">Hello</div>
  <div class="second block">Hi</div>
  <div class="third block">hello</div>
</div>
```

The `transition-property` Property defines which properties to transition so, I put: `width`, `height` and `color`. You can change what you wanna transition

Comment: it's nice but I need a smooth animation

Comment: hmm.. I will update if got that smooth animation

Answer (score 0):

Just change offset values of that element on click.